# Variable symbol conventions?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I know that there are some symbols that are frequently used for certain variables. For example, $n$ is commonly used to denote some quantity etc...

So, what if $n$ has already been used? Can we use just *any* symbol? Like $\psi$, $\lambda$, $\omega$, etc...

By the way, I'm in high school; I'm not too familiar with the world of math.

Comment: certain symbols are traditional ($n$ for natural number, $x$ for real number, $z$ for complex number, $\theta$ for angle, etc.), but as long as you define it, the choice of symbol is your prerogative as the author

Comment: Ah! I guess it's solved then. Thanks

Comment: Try to use letters and symbols that are easy to remember and are the first letter of the term to which they refer.  In high-school, my physics teacher once gave us a hilarious problem that would have been simple but for the variables... something like:  "consider a mass $x$ moving along the vertical ($\pi$) axis, with acceleration $\theta$ a distance $\phi_b$ from sphere of radius $y$, striking it at angle $m$...."  Well you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Certain symbols are traditional in mathematics (e.g., $n$ for natural number, $q$ for rational number, $x$ for real number, $z$ for complex number, $\theta$ for angle, $\phi$ for the golden mean, $e$ for the base of natural logarithms, $\pi$ for the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter, $\lambda$ for eigenvalue, $i$ for square root of $-1$, $\omega$ for complex cube root of unity, etc.), but, as long as you define it, the choice of symbol is your prerogative as the author.

Comment: I would highly discourage using $\pi$ or $e$ to represent anything other than constants. The prime counting function $\pi(x)$ is awful enough.

Comment: $e$ sometimes represents a group [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element)